# Ajax php reloading into divs example

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having issues with reloading a php file into 3 separate divs independently via ajax.
There is a ton of old code out there so I'm trying to find the most recent elegant solution.
I based this version on this code from https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax which loads a text file.

The main index.php file has 3 containers with div1, div2, and div3 areas in each.
There is a button for each which should reload a php page called colors.php into each separate div. The colors.php page shows a different color every time it loads. It's this. Reload the page to see color change.
http://spillway.com/example/colors.php

Here is the attempt
http://spillway.com/example

Thanks for any info.

The code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ajax php reload div example</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<!-- set up div links with ajax -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "colors.php", success: function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
        
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "colors.php", success: function(result){
      $("#div2").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "colors.php", success: function(result){
      $("#div3").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>

<!-- CSS for divs and containers -->

    <style>
        
        
    .container1 {
          position: absolute;
          margin: auto;
          border: 3px solid green;
          text-align: center;
          left: 100px;
          top: 25%;
          padding: 10px;
      }
    .container2 {
          position: absolute;
          margin: auto;
          border: 3px solid green;
          text-align: center;
          left: 500px;
          top: 25%;
          padding: 10px;
      }
    .container3 {
          position: absolute;
          margin: auto;
          border: 3px solid green;
          text-align: center;
          left: 900px;
          top: 25%;
          padding: 10px;
      }
    .div1 {
          margin: auto;
          border: 3px solid green;
          text-align: center;
          left: 100px;
          top: 25%;
          padding: 10px;
      }
    .div2 {
          margin: auto;
          border: 3px solid green;
          text-align: center;
          left: 100px;
          top: 25%;
          padding: 10px;
      }
    .div3 {
          margin: auto;
          border: 3px solid green;
          text-align: center;
          left: 100px;
          top: 25%;
          padding: 10px;
      } 
        
    </style>
    


    
<body>
<!-- container divs and div1 div2 div3 with buttons -->


<!-- first div --------------------------------------------------->
    
    <div class="container1">
        <button>reload color php</button><br>
        <div class="div1">
        <h2>div1</h2>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
<!-- second div --------------------------------------------------->    
    <div class="container2">
        <button>reload color php</button><br>
        <div class="div2">
        <h2>div2</h2>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
<!-- third div ---------------------------------------------------> 
    <div class="container3">
        <button>reload color php</button><br>
        <div class="div3">
        <h2>div3</h2>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are having is you are adding more than one click handler to `button`, not a specific button but ALL of them.

You can use a single event handler that simply gets the parent div of the button that was clicked, then finds the div as a child that will hold the content and use that as the target.

Another problem that you are having is the files that you are loading via ajax actually include FULL html/body tags but they shouldn't they should just the HTML elements only (or JSON but for my example I'm using HTML).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    target = $(this).parent("div").find("div");
    $.ajax({url: "colors.php", success: function(result){
      target.html(result);
    }});
  });
});
```

css

```
.color-div{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

for your color files just include the div with the background color and a class that gives the div size.

```
<div class='color-div' style='background-color:#FF0000'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I discovered that the div is referencing a class instead of an ID which seemed to work for text when I tried just one button. http://www.spillway.com/example/index-1div-txt.html   

But I still cannot get even an .html to load in the div with this code. Another test of just one button. http://www.spillway.com/example/index-1div.php

It should just load this html page http://www.spillway.com/example/red.html

Comment: @JohnCulhane I updated my answer to include the other problem you are having with a solution for it.